# How to scrape data from main listing page as well as detail pagefor that particular listing using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling a website with property listings and the "Buy/Rent" is only found in the listing page.I have extracted other data from the detail page by parsing each urls to the parse_property method from parse method, however i am not able to get the offering type from the main listing page.

I have tried to do it the same way i parsed individual urls.(The commented code)

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        properties = response.xpath('//div[@class="property-information-address"]/a')
            for property in properties:
                url= property.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_property, meta={'URL':url})
    # TODO: offering

    # offering=response.xpath('//div[@class="property-status"]')
    #     for of in offerings:
    #         offering=of.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first()
    #         yield Request(offering, callback=self.parse_property, meta={'Offering':offering})

        next_page=response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/a/@href')[-2].extract()
        yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_property(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=NPMItem(), response=response)
        url=response.meta.get('URL')
        #offer=response.meta.get('Offering')
        l.add_value('URL', response.url)
        #l.add_value('Offering', response.offer)
```

Comment: It is hard to suggest anything without link to concrete page or piece of html.

Comment: @vezunchik here is the link to the [page](https://www.kathmanduhomesearch.com/property/?post_type=property&search_keyword&status&price-min&price-max&city&state&beds&baths&ptype&sqft&submit=Search)

Comment: Add `yield l.load_item()` in the end of your `parse_property` function and your code should work fine.

Comment: @vezunchik The parse function sends link to the parse_property which then extracts data from that link.I need a way to pass the rent/sale from the listing to the parse_property function just like the url.And yes there is a 'yield l.load_item()' in the parse_property function which is working.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Thank you for clarifications. I've added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to rely on element, which is higher in DOM-tree, and scrape both property type and link from there. Check this code example, it works:

```
def parse(self, response):
    properties = response.xpath('//div[@class="property-listing"]')
    for property in properties:
        url = property.xpath('.//div[@class="property-information-address"]/a/@href').get()
        ptype = property.xpath('.//div[@class="property-status"]/a/text()').get()
        yield response.follow(url, self.parse_property, meta={'ptype': ptype})

    next_page = response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').get()
    if next_page:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_property(self, response):
    print '======'
    print response.meta['ptype']
    print '======'
    # build your item here, printing is only to show content of `ptype`
```